# Do hobbyist dynos run out of dyno hours?

Tags: heroku

Do hobbyist dynos run out of dyno hours?

I have a website hosted on heroku and I also have other websites and apps hosted on heroku too so 10 days before the end of every month the dynos shutdown. So if I upgrade one website to Hobbyist dynos, will that website not shutdown at the end of every month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- **Free Dyno**: register a valid credit card to obtain additional 450 free dyno hours (total of 1000hrs). Note the Dynos will still go to sleep after 30 min inactivity (no incoming requests)
- **Hobby Dyno**: pay for Hobby subscription. There is no limit on the hours and it doesn't sleep after 30 min inactivity.